# Can i use the derivation rules on a couse of real analysis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Hello I have been presented with a question about differentiability of a function in a course of real analysis, and as a course of real analysis expects much more rigor than a course of calculus usually does, I have been pondering if it is alright to use the rules of differentiation to find the derivative if those were not yet covered in the course and therefore don't are expected to be taken as truth, of course i could always prove them by myself in the exercise, but then I though that all those rules are derived from the limit definition of a derivative (or the limit of a newton's quotient as my Calculus I professor would say).

Therefore i thought that, being logically equivalent,  I could always use the definition to calculate the derivatives.Nevertheless when faced with the function: 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x\not=0 \\
0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

And when I used the definition of a derivative:
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

I then found that, when applied at a point $x_0\not=0$, I could not find any way of simplifying the resultant quotient as to take the limit in any elementary way. Now I have the following question about the logic behind the definition of a derivative and the rules of differentiation, if they are logically equivalent, shouldn't all the results that I get from the rules be possible to be derived using only the definition directly ? Is there any way that I could actually simplify the limit expression and get the derivative in a direct way ? If the rules and the definition are not logically equivalent, from where comes the additional information that makes it possible to calculate the derivative ?

Comment: For $x_0\ne 0$, $\frac1x $ is differentiable.  Hence, $\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable since it's a composite of a differentiable function of a differentiable function.  Finally, inasmuch as $x^2$ is differentiable and the product of differentiable functions is also differentiable, then we are done.

Comment: If your question is what you are expected to do on homework assignments for your course, you should just ask your instructor.  Different courses will handle this in different ways.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey It is not a question about that, it is just the context of were my doubt originated from.

Comment: In a more concise way, my question is why I can't derive the expression of the derivative of this function directly from the limit definition, Is it simply because I am not smart enough to find a way to simplify the limit or is it because fundamentally it cannot be obtained from the definition ?

Comment: Well if the function is given in terms of formula made of elementary functions (or functions whose derivatives are available by some formula) then it makes sense to use laws of derivatives. For a complicated expression using the limit definition of derivative is a pain and the process is equal to the one used in proof of derivative laws. This is applicable if $x_{0}\neq 0$. For $x_{0}=0$ you need to use the limit definition because the formula for original function does not make sense for $x_{0}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the derivative laws if you can use limit laws and continuity of $\sin$, $\cos$ and rational functions (not at poles). Suppose $x_0\neq 0$ and any $h$ near $0$ such that $x_0+h \neq 0$, then

\begin{align}
&\frac{(x_0+h)^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) - x_0^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x_0}\right)}{h}\\
&= \frac{x_0^2\left[ \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) - \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0} \right)\right] + 2hx_0\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) + h^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)}{h}\\
%
&= \frac{x_0^2}{h}\cdot 2 \cos \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x_0+h} + \frac{1}{x_0}}{2}\right) \sin\left( \frac{\frac{1}{x_0+h} - \frac{1}{x_0}}{2}\right) +
2x_0\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) + h \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)\\
%
&= \frac{x_0^2}{h}\cdot 2 \cos \left(\frac{2x_0+h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right) \sin\left( - \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right) +
2x_0\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) + h \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)\\
%
&= -\frac{2x_0^2}{h} \cos \left(\frac{2x_0+h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right) \frac{ \sin\left( \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right)}{ \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)} } \cdot \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)} +
2x_0\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right) + h \sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)\\
%
&= -\underbrace{\frac{x_0}{x_0+h}}_{\to 1} \underbrace{\cos \left(\frac{2x_0+h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right)}_{\to \cos(1/x_0)} \underbrace{\frac{ \sin\left( \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)}\right)}{ \frac{h}{2x_0(x_0+h)} }}_{\to 1} +
2x_0\underbrace{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)}_{\to\sin(1/x_0)} + \underbrace{h}_{\to 0} \underbrace{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x_0+h} \right)}_{\sin(1/x_0)}\\
&\to -\cos\left(\frac{1}{x_0}\right) + 2x_0\sin\left(\frac{1}{x_0}\right)
\end{align}
as $h\to 0$.

The $x_0=0$ case is trivial,

$$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{h^2\sin \frac{1}{h} - 0}{h}
= h\sin \frac{1}{h}$$
and so
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{u = 1/h \to \pm \infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u} = 0$$

Comment: Why?$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: @Zachary Selk Why what? OP said they had issues simplifying the resultant quotient. I wanted to show that you don't need to use the chain rule or product rule nor even differentiability of $\sin$ or $\cos$. Every step could be turned into an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ type proof, but really we only need limit rules.

Comment: Basically showing that while the accepted answer is good, it is wrong as to the extent of what is necessary for proof. Actually far less is required than that answer implied. There would have been no point in me rehashing the "ask your professor what they expect"-type answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for this demonstration, so in the general case one can only do $ \varepsilon -\delta $ if one wishes not to use use the chain rule or product rule nor differentiability of know functions ?

Comment: @adfriedman I'm not sure my answer is "wrong" in the sense that that "far less is required" than I indicated.  Note that your first couple of lines parallel the proof of the product rule (in this special case), and that the rest of the proof shows that a restricted version the the chain rule holds for $\sin$.  I'll also note that you did not show that $\frac{\sin(h)}{h} \to 1$, which is an important step in demonstrating the differentiability of $\sin$.

Comment: It only parallels the product in that I rearrange terms. You might as well complain that I am implicitly using field axioms or trig identities the OP might not be familiar with. I am merely addressing that no knowledge of differentiability is required to evaluate the limit of the quotient.

Answer (score 3):

In a course on analysis, the goal is typically to *prove* that the computations in an introductory calculus class are justified, and to place them on a firm theoretical foundation.  The computational results of calculus (i.e. the "rules" for differentiation) are *implied by* the axioms and resulting theorems.  They are *not* logically equivalent (you can construct operators that behave like the derivative which don't come from difference quotients in the same way).  Thus you really do need to prove that the computations work before you can use them, and cannot blithely apply them willy-nilly.

---

To deal with your function, there are several theorems and lemmata that we might want to prove first:

1. If $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} h(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L$ (the squeeze theorem—you'll need this to prove differentiability at zero).
2. If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$, then $fg$ is differentiable at that point (and $(fg)'(x) = (f'g + fg')(x)$, i.e. the product rule; though you don't really need that here, as you are not trying to find the derivative).
3. If $g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$, then $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $x$ (and $(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$, i.e. the chain rule; again, you don't really need the formula for your problem).
4. The functions $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

If I were teaching this class, I would have proved the above four results in lecture (or assigned them as homework) before assigning the problem above.  In that context, I would expect my students to cite those results, but not to reprove them.  On the other hand, it is possible (though tedious) to get at the derivative directly from the definition.  However, I suspect that you would end up reproving the product rule and the chain rule in a special case in the process, thus I would be surprised if that was the intent of the exercise.

That being said, only your instructor knows what s/he *actually* wants from you.  I would suggest attending office hours and seeking clarification.

Comment: So you admit it being possible to get the derivative directly from the definition, but it possibly taking many steps and being in general not recommendable. Although I had already expected that it would be rather troublesome, i would love to see such a proof because it would probably involve some unusual reasoning to solve such a problem.

Comment: Your comment made me realize that i am probably past the stage of exercises that have the theory completely covered on the class, and that I shouldn't be doing those yet, but nevertheless it was always something that incommoded me.

Comment: Very good answer. I hope most instructors follow the idea you have mentioned.

Comment: @FelipeDilho Of course i tis possible to get the derivative directly from the definition.  If a function is differentiable, then we can get the derivative directly from the definition.  I just think that it is tedious, and not really a good use of a student's (or anyone else's) time.  Though I do appreciate that adfriedman went through the effort of typing out the details.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac {\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{\frac{1}{h}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z}$$. Now $|\sin z/z|\le|1/z|$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}1/z=0$. Hence the required limit is $0$.

Comment: Yes but that is not my question, i haven't ever mentioned calculating the derivative at point $x_0=0$.

Comment: Oh so sorry, but in that case you can always use the fact that since both the functions $\sin(1/x)$ and $x^2$ are differentiable at nonzero $x$ so should be their product and use the derivation rule for the product of differentiable functions $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$

Comment: This only implies the right hand side derivative exists. You need $z\to\pm \infty$.